# Cannot clone object

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, parameters

I was Tunning Parameter

```
def create_model(layers, activation):
    model = Sequential()
    for i, nodes in enumerate(layers):
        if i==0:
            model.add(Dense(nodes,input_dim=X_train.shape[1]))
            model.add(Activation(activation))
            model.add(Dropout(0.3))
        else:
            model.add(Dense(nodes))
            model.add(Activation(activation))
            model.add(Dropout(0.3))
            
    model.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer= 'glorot_uniform', activation = 'sigmoid')) # Note: no activation beyond this point
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
    
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)

layers = [[20], [40, 20], [45, 30, 15]]
activations = ['sigmoid', 'relu']
param_grid = dict(layers=layers, activation=activations, batch_size = [128, 256], epochs=[30])
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I got an error and I don't know how to solve it

Error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot clone object <tensorflow.python.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier object at 0x000001B705FFB7F0>, as the constructor either does not set or modifies parameter layers
```

Comment: Instead of using sklearn GridSearch you should use keras tuner. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/keras_tuner For detailed examples please see:
https://keras-team.github.io/keras-tuner/

Comment: Try to have a look [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/66341/cannot-clone-object-keras-wrappers-scikit-learn-kerasregressor-object-at-0x7fdc), too. It will link to a related issue in `keras`. [Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15722) is an issue raised in `scikit-learn` wrt the argument.